# Save output file from 'stats' command in gnuplot?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I want to save the output from the 'stats' command in gnuplot as a file.
I try to analyse multiple .dat files and compare them according to their min, max, mean, std derivation. So I need to create a single file containing these values, possible even from all my 600 .dat files in one

Comment: From `help stats`: "The summary is printed to the screen by default.
 Output can be redirected to a file by prior use of the command `set print`, or suppressed altogether using the `nooutput` option."

Comment: @user8153, yes, it can be redirected to a file, but very strange that it cannot be redirected to a datablock, e.g. `set print $Statistics; stats $Data; set print` doesn't work, in case you want to directly use it in gnuplot again. So apparently, you have to go via a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know than your question is `linux` tagged. But may this answer (under Windows) maybe help you.
Suppose that you have `.dat` files containing like this:

```txt
# File 01.dat
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

```txt
# File 02.dat
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

```txt
# File 03.dat
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

To prints the minimum value of each file do you do this:

```c
ListOfFiles = system('dir /b *.dat') # Get all .dat files in current directory
set print 'MinValues.log'            # Define a filename to save the values
    do for [file in ListOfFiles]{    # Loop for each file in 'ListOfFiles'
        stats file nooutput          # Get statistics and turn off the output
        print STATS_min              # Print the minimum into file
    }                                # Close the loop
unset print                          # Turn off the print
```

The `MinValues.log` now contains:

```txt
1.0
11.0
21.0
```

You would can use the same logic to create one file with max, mean values or creates more columns instead.

I hope this be useful.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the  call "system('dir /b *.dat')" is not working. "warning: Skipping unreadable file "dir" - Can't read data file". I tried "system("ls -1 data_*.dat")" which seems to be okay, except it adds an " to the first and last file.
However, now I get the "undefined variable: STATS_min"- error message

Comment: `STATS_min` be available if you use only one column to perform statistical analysis, like in my example. If you need use two columns, `stats file using 1:2 nooutput` must be used. In this case you will find `STATS_min_x` and `STATS_min_y` to first and second columns, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am responding too late, this might be useful in future

```
set print 'stats_output_file"
stats 'data_file' using 1:2
```